# Represent a nil list and/or a list(nil)

Tags: list, f#, null

#### Background

We are implementing this algorithm in F#.

[image]

Here is a little bit more information [from Topor (1982)](https://github.com/shaunluttin/algorithms/blob/master/articles/functional-programs-for-generating-permutations/article.pdf) about the notation that the algorithm uses:

> Formally, a `'t list` is either `null` (denoted `nil`) or has a `hd` (which is a `'t`) and a `tl` (which is a `'t list`)... If `x` is a list, we test whether it is `null` by writing `null x`... We create a new list, adding the element `a` at the front of an existing list `x`, by writing `a:x`... We denote the unit list containing the element `a` by `list(a)`... `list(x) = x:nil`.

#### Question

What we're wondering is how in F# to express those `nil`, `null`, and `list(nil)` values. For instance, should we be using the Option type, an empty list, or something else?

#### What We Have Tried

```
let rec kpermute k (xs: 't list) = 

    let rec mapPerm k xs ys =
        match ys with 
        | [] -> []
        | head::tail -> 
            let kpermuteNext = kpermute (k-1) (removeFirst head xs)
            let mapPermNext = mapPerm k xs tail
            mapcons head kpermuteNext mapPermNext

    match k with 
    | 0 -> [[]]
    | _ when xs.Length < k -> []
    | _ -> mapPerm k xs xs
```

When working with lists, for `list(nil)` we use `[[]]` and for `nil` we use `[]`. While that's fine, there might be a more expressive way to do it. There are also times when we use `List.empty<'t list>` and `List.empty<'t>` when the type inference needs more information.

Comment: Moderators: if this question is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, please feel free to move it there.

Comment: It says right in the quote that you're quoting: `nil` is an empty list. Why would you use an option type? Where did you get that from? Also: who's "we"?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin There is no clear mentioned of an empty list in the quote. Where do you see that? About the `Option` type, it might be appropriate because it allows `None`, which expresses that there is no value, which is similar to what `null` expresses in C#. About the "we", that refers to myself and the other people who are working on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper gives you all the answers: `nil` is `[]`; `null x` is a test for whether `x` is the empty list; `list(nil)` is `[[]]`.

The naïve translation of algorithm B to F# is as follows:

```
let rec minus a = function
    | [] -> failwith "empty list"
    | xh :: xt -> if xh = a then xt else xh :: minus a xt

let rec permute2 k x =
    if k = 0 then [[]]
    elif List.length x < k then []
    else mapperm k x x

and mapperm k x = function
    | [] -> []
    | yh :: yt -> mapcons yh (permute2 (minus yh x)) (mapperm x yt)

and mapcons a ps qs =
    match ps with
    | [] -> qs
    | ph :: pt -> a :: ph :: mapcons a pt qs
```

Comment: There is probably something in the paper that is obvious that we are missing. In the spirit of teaching, can you point out where the paper shows that `nil` is `[]`. It is clear that that works, and that is what we thought too, but we're left wondering where the paper says that, and why using `None` would also not be an appropriate interpretation. In functional programming, is a null list generally considered equivalent to an empty list? If we were using C# instead, would using `null` be appropriate or is an empty list there too the right answer.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: The author of the paper uses Lisp terminology… on page 1: 'Formally, an α-list is either null (denoted nil) or has a hd (which is an α) and a tl (which is an α-list).' This description fits exactly with an F# list, which is either empty (``[]``), or a list with a head and a tail (``hd :: tl``).

Comment: And yes, in C# an empty list would probably be represented as null.